# How to change style of X-Axis or Y-Axis Name on hover in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

I tried rich text for name but I am not able to find any way to add on hover style changes like font size, color, shadow. I looked in `nameTextStyle` key as well but it's not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the [triggerEvent](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.triggerEvent) property of the axis to `true` you can catch the [hover event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events.mouseover) and use [setOption](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption) to customize everything to your needs.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurNAIYC2ApkQOTa54ByV1dANCemAE4QBzAdV4BRAG7VoYInwCu1LqVhgAniFqw6AY3JhqA4L1WdusACZ7yRANp0AsjE5aAKgud0A6tXMeXACzkPADF-DwBlPQi5aDoAXRIAXyVYVRx8IlRlChp6NKZWGlNlPkFhMUlpWV4FFJ51TTpxcgAbdySUvBEIakJYGzMs5QsrWwBGAFYABg5YACYAZhn5uYAWWbmxgA5ZsYWJ3dWAdg2ANim4utI1DXoWiGh2M0SSBMSAbhQUSlUAYX9yLwwAA6GAACjolGAci6wEkvGc2gB0GEv2ALSMAEpPj9_oCQeDIdDYXIwIjkaj0VjPigAGYxbSQGCwJHkFHUNEY3hgkCAqh4THEdAQWmwHl8yh4YFgQHCMAuBoIeCIOjkApsOiCoboFrUMAsqm8T7KEVi3m8fnSxXKlVQmHUOEiTVC4baQ0ILS8Hx0Y2kF7KMxu6B4fVq_Ae82Wt2UEAwKTyhq-9BBkOwUBMuCIJAfMzpqDQGxhvBxD1IHLUFzUDBgcJqXWZN1coiNoyJHPKXEAoHArpgADy4HzYLzMGxSRQiSAA):

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    name: 'xAxisName',
    triggerEvent: true,
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    name: 'yAxisName',
    triggerEvent: true,
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};

myChart.on('mouseover', changeColor);
myChart.on('mouseout', changeColor);

function changeColor(params) {
  if (params.targetType === 'axisName') {
    let color;
    if (params.type === 'mouseover') {
      color = 'red';
    }
    
    const axis = params.componentType;
    const option = {};
    option[axis] = {nameTextStyle: {color: color}};
    myChart.setOption(option);
  }
}
```